# Any philosophical insight to the concept of "usefulness" in drug discovery?

Tags: drug-design

Any philosophical insight to the concept of "usefulness" in drug discovery?

I mean, I started to naively view drug design and computational drug design as some sort of holy grail (we can design the things we need/want).

Then after reading few papers I'm finding that the studied phenomena seem quite complicated. There are different risks, models and multiple interactions.

This made me question whether drug design is useful at all. Or when is it?

I'm looking for an answer that answers e.g.:

- When are drugs useful?
- Perceptions on costs (time, money, stress) vs benefits of drugs and drug design.
- Perceptions on the efficiency of "accurate models" in drug design.

This is e.g. because (naive example):

- Exercise is as effective as a SSRI, but it costs little to produce and has well-known side-effects.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but you're asking too many questions at once. Please see this: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5 Please narrow it down to just ***one*** question such as "When are drugs useful?" and ensure that it's asked within the context of matter modeling.